# How to add tocuh gesture in PDFAnnotation

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer, pdfkit, ios-pdfkit

Anyone Work on PDFKit, I draw a custom Annotation in PDFView, But I want to add action in Custom Annotation and I can't able to add Gesture in PDFAnnotation because it does not inherit from UIView, so is there any way to add Gesture in PDFAnnotation. See the custom Annotation in this image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkNAO.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to add GestureRecognizer for PDFAnnotation ios swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48743372/how-to-add-gesturerecognizer-for-pdfannotation-ios-swift-4)

Comment: I Used that code this way

Comment: @objc func titleTapped(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)  {
        let tapLocation = gestureRecognizer.location(in: pdfViewObj)
        let tappedPage = pdfView.page(for: tapLocation, nearest: false)
        if let page = tappedPage {
            let tapPageLocation = pdfView.convert(tapLocation, to: page)
            let annotation = page.annotation(at: tapPageLocation)
            print("anotation : \(annotation)")
        }
    }

Comment: but my code is crashing while we tap on Outside of any annotations. at this line.            let tapLocation = gestureRecognizer.location(in: pdfViewObj)

Comment: and error is Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteNotification locationInView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000006a0fc0'